# MVC RTSP forwarding request

Tags: model-view-controller, ffmpeg, rtsp, ip-camera, rtsp-client

I'd like to restream my rtsp ip camera to be accessible from outside by make request to my web server. I have play around using ffserver and ffmpeg. But it always gave me about 10 seconds of latency on whatever setting. I have tried -fflags nobuffer, playing the value of probesize and analyzeduration, add zerolatency, etc. So I gave up using ffserver to be used as restreaming server.

If there is no restreaming, just using the ffmpeg to output to a file or view, it gaves low latency below 1 sec.

Now I am thinking to let the client to have indirect access to the camera to eliminate using restreaming server. My question is, how to forward a rtsp request coming to my server to my ip camera. My web server has 2 network interface. One for internal, which the ip camera connected, and the other for public access. I'd like to keep my ip camera keep private in internal network/not exposed to the internet. So I would like to forward incoming rtsp request to my ip camera.

I work in MVC and IIS 7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't understand what MVC or IIS has to do with this.

If you want to restream the IP camera RTSP, I would suggest
using the [RTSP proxy](http://www.live555.com/proxyServer/) from live555. The live555 code is
cross platform and you can run this proxy on your web server.

Comment: That's what I am looking for..!! You're my life saviour. Thank you.! I thought it should be easy but I got lost with ffserver. And about MVC to redirect rtsp stream just a thought since I don't know that there is live555 which can be used as proxy. Thank you again.